# How to Make Sure SQL Alchemy ORM Translates Each Numerical Object to Raw Query Correctly?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, amazon-athena, pyathena

Using SQL Alchemy ORM to query an AWS athena database.
First off, here is the raw SQL query, which is working perfectly

```sql
WITH zi AS (SELECT
       trip.start_dt,
       address.zone_id
FROM view_midtable_esc_trip_details_cleaned AS trip
INNER JOIN view_midtable_esc_address_expanded AS address
ON trip.start_address_ref = address.address_ref),

all_trips AS (SELECT
date_parse(
        concat(
            date_format(zi.start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:'),
-- The following line causing issues when converting to ORM
            CAST(FLOOR(extract(minute from zi.start_dt)/15)*15 AS VARCHAR),
            ':00'),
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
    ) AS modified_timestamp,
    zi.zone_id
FROM zi)

SELECT COUNT(*) as demand,
modified_timestamp,
zone_id FROM all_trips GROUP BY modified_timestamp, zone_id;
```

Now, here is the relevant part of the code where I am doing the minutes extraction from the timestamp, and replacing it with the following logic

> floor(original_minutes/15)*15

```py
minutes_interval:int=15
quantised_minute:BinaryExpression=func.FLOOR(func.extract('minute', 
zi.columns[original_timestamp])/minutes_interval)*minutes_interval
modified_timestamp = func.date_format(func.concat(
    func.date_format(zi.columns[original_timestamp], '%Y-%m-%d %H:'),
func.CAST(quantised_minute, VARCHAR)), 
                                      text("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'")).label(name=original_timestamp)    
query:Query=session.query(modified_timestamp, 
                          zi.columns[zone_col], 
                          func.count().label(name=LABEL)).group_by(modified_timestamp, zi.columns[zone_col])
```

When I print the raw query that is sent to the engine, this is getting translated by ORM as (comments and formatting mine)

```
SELECT date_format(concat(date_format(anon_1.start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:'), 
-- What is this extra casting?
CAST(FLOOR(EXTRACT(minute FROM anon_1.start_dt) / CAST(15 AS NUMERIC)) * 15 AS VARCHAR)), 

'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS start_dt, anon_1.zone_id, count(*) AS total_unique_demand 
FROM ...
```

and the python error message is

```
OperationalError: (pyathena.error.OperationalError) TYPE_MISMATCH: line 1:123: Unknown type: NUMERIC
[SQL: SELECT date_format(concat(date_format(anon_1.start_dt, '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:'), CAST(FLOOR(EXTRACT(minute FROM anon_1.start_dt) / CAST(15 AS NUMERIC)) * 15 AS VARCHAR)), '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i') AS start_dt, anon_1.zone_id, count(*) AS total_unique_demand
```

Of course, this is not the whole code and the whole query, but this *incorrect* translation (when forming the query from the ORM representation) is the core issue here. Is this a documented concept that I should be aware of?

Also, I tried replacing the simple number with some variations of `sqlalchemy.text(text=str(minutes_interval)`, but did not help.

I am using pyathena for engine, and AWS athena database.

Comment: SQLAlchemy [tries to enforce true division when the / operator is used](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#python-division-operator-performs-true-division-for-all-backends-added-floor-division), so it casts to `NUMERIC` to the result includes decimal values. I don't know why PyAthena is raising, as it seems to have had support for `NUMERIC` for the past three years. Perhaps you can try using  literal `15.0` and see if that gets handled better?